# Photoshop CS3 animation opacity problems

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, transparency, animation

[image: sample image]

Here is my dilemma. I am making a scrolling text gif. I need the background on this gif to be transparent with a white box centered in the middle with the text showing ONLY in the white box. This means that the text needs to only show up on the box and not the transparent background.

Comment: Could you post an example? My assumption is that you are talking about masks but I could be wrong. If you are talking about masks, then [this would be a worthwhile read](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/12/17/unveiling-photoshop-masks/). At which point you'd want to mask your text to only stay in the white box.

Comment: I tried to post a sample of what i was trying to accomplish but I dont have enough reputation in the forums to be able to post an image.

Comment: Ive used masks in photoshop on occasion. Im not sure if it would help in this occasion. What I need is more of some way to make the text transparent when its in the blank part of the canvas, then start showing once it hits the white rectangle, scroll through the rectangle and then disappear again as it goes back into the transparent background on the other end of the graphic.

Comment: Just edit your question, add the image and delete the leading ! A user with more rep can activate your image for you :-)

Comment: Edited it, wow the scrolling text is pretty slow. sorry about that. Anyways, I just want the text to gradually show up in the colored box as it enters it and then gradually disappear as it leave the box.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I think Johannes comment is probably the key to what im attempting to accomplish. Ive been playing with the masks and almost have it I think. Thanks everyone for your suggestions and your time. Thank you again everyone!

Comment: I increased the speed of the animation in the sample.

Comment: @user12702 I rolled back your edit to the question. Posting the corrected images won't assist future visitors having the same issue. You should leave the incorrect image so that others can see the problem. Then they can read answers for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Johannes' comment was correct. You simply need a mask to hide the text outside the rounded rectangle.

I'm merely using your posted gif as a base. The actual Photoshop document will most likely be set up differently, but this is the basic item you need.

Highlight all but the bottom layer in the Layers Panel and group those layers (Layer > Group Layers).

Create a selection which matches the rounded rectangle. Then with the Group highlighted in the Layers Panel, and the selection active, click the little mask icon at the bottom of the Layers Panel. This will add a mask to the group.

[image: layers]

This will then hide the text outside the rectangle. (I've increased the animation speed considerably so it can be seen better.)

[image: animation]

When setting up the animation, I assume you have only one layer for the scrolling text and are moving it and then creating a motion tween between frames. When you do that, you want to **unlink the layer and the mask** by clicking the little chain icon between them. This will allow you to move the text, while leaving the mask in a stationary position.

Comment: Great Scott !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Brilliant! Thats exactly what it is I needed to do. I've rarely used animation in Photoshop so im not as familiar with it as I would like. I appreciate everyone's input on this immensely! Have an epic day!

Comment: @Bala I know, this is heavy!